# Trouble sorting my erb view into groups with in_groups_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I am trying to use in_groups_of to sort my rails html output into two columns.  Right now it just displays as one column.  Here is the code:

```
<% @providers.in_groups_of(2).each do |group| %>
<div class="row">

  <% group.each do |provider| %>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h3><%= link_to provider.name, provider_path(provider) %></h3>


      <h4><%= provider.address %></h4>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: I understand the grid but generally for two columns you would use col-md-6, and I don't see two places for dividers here

Comment: Check the generated HTML it might give some hints

Comment: I checked it and made a few changes but still just displays as one column.  Each group of 2 should display across 12 cols based on what I have right?

Comment: You're right about `col-md-6`. There are two spaces because you have a two-element loop around it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `div.col-md-12`s are *each* taking up the width of an entire row. Try changing them to `col-xs-6`. (I'm using `xs` so it will show up on any size of window; ignore this if not appropriate to your situation.)

```
<% @provider.in_groups_of(2).each do |group| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% group.each do |provider| %>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h3><%= link_to provider.name, provider_path(provider) %></h3>
        <h4><%= provider.address %></h4>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `@provider` is an enumerable of some sort, right? I only ask because it would usually be named `@providers` (with an s) if it is...

Comment: Other than that, I have a feeling we might be missing some context here - I can't see any reason that this wouldn't work as it stands.

Comment: Yeah your right it should have been @providers but I just changed it and I still get the 1 column.  I'm trying to make the index of providers display in two columns,

Comment: You could also try debugging a bit with `<%= group.inspect %>` at the top of the outer loop...

Comment: I added it and I'm not getting anything on the server demo.  Am I supposed to use the console or something?

Comment: No, it should be on the web page. If nothing is changing, it may be that what you're changing is not what is actually being served to the browser...